# Visual Studio 2012 usability bugs

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Our team is thinking of upgrading to Visual Studio 2012, are there any common bugs that may cause hassle? Typically when a system is released, there are a few major bugs that were missed completely by the development team (eg. The entire Vista operating system)

Comment: Also links to good bug list resources would be very useful!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any "known" issues for VS 2012.  There's usually a note or two in the readme; but, I cannot find one.  You can view all the bugs (and other feedback) on Connect http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/SearchResults.aspx?FeedbackType=0&Status=1&Scope=0&SortOrder=5&TabView=0

Also, there's a UserVoice site for Visual Studio, so you can see what other people are suggesting to see if there is anything there that might be a show-stopper: http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio