# Visual Studio 2012: Test not executed

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012

My VS2012 has recently started acting wierd. I'm using MS Test with tests written in C# to test our unmanaged C++/C# code implemented as a number of DLLs. Since today, running a selected test does nothing.

When I right-click on a test in Test Explorer and select "Debug Slected Tests", breakpoints are not hit, and the test never completes. When I select "Run Selected Tests", also nothing happens and the test never completes. The status at the top of the Test Explorer window changes from "Run All" to "Cancel", however, the slow-scrolling bar at the top indicating that the test is in progress is not displayed.

I suspect that Test Explorer cannot load the code DLLs. I confirm that the test successfully compiles and links. IS there a way to debug this? When I attempt to display the loaded modules using Debug | Windows, there is no Modules option displayed, only Breakpoint, Output and Immediate

If this has already been answered, please attach a link.

Many thanks.

Comment: Does *Test* -> *Debug* -> *Debug all tests* hit any breakpoints? Can you confirm that you rebuild your *entire* solution?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11996755/visual-studio-2012-usability-bugs

Comment: Just edited post to indicate I cannot display loaded Modules. Also, normally when an out-of-date exe is being run, the breakpoint dot change to indicate they are not reachable. Not in this case. I confirm that the entire solution was rebuilt.